# How do deal with large numbe in Android Kotlin Apps?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple Android app that calculates the factorial of a number. The problem is that whenever I enter a number larger then 5 digits the app stops.

Logcat:

```
Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Background concurrent copying GC freed 131318(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 80us total 194.279ms
```

Kotlin Code:

```
package com.example.paciu.factorial

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.math.BigInteger


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

tailrec fun tail_recursion_factorial(n: BigInteger, factorialOfN: BigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(2)): BigInteger {
    return when (n) {
        BigInteger.ZERO -> BigInteger.ONE
        BigInteger.ONE -> BigInteger.ONE
        BigInteger.valueOf(2) -> factorialOfN
        else -> {
            tail_recursion_factorial(n.minus(BigInteger.ONE), n.times(factorialOfN))
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnFact.setOnClickListener {
        var n = editText.text.toString()
        try {
            when {
                BigInteger(n) < BigInteger.ZERO -> textView.text = "Sorry bro! Can't do a factorial to a negative number."
                BigInteger(n) >= BigInteger.ZERO -> {
                    textView.text = "$n! is ${tail_recursion_factorial(BigInteger(n))}"
                    System.gc()

                }
            }
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            textView.text = "Sorry bro! Can't do that ..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to this field, so can anyone help me understanding why this is happening?

Comment: As the message says, you are doing too much work on the MainThread which main purpose is to draw the UI, receive callbacks and handle user inputs. Any other expensive work should be moved to a background thread and since you are doing recursion, you definitely should use a background thread for this. Check the AsyncTask for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs on UI [thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and there are time limits your code can spend running on that thred w/o returning back to the system. Your code exceed that limits and as result your app is considered stalled and get killed by the system because with Application Not Responding dialog. To prevent this, you must move your calculations to separate thread, ie. by using [Kotlin's coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) or [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or so.

In general you need to read [Keeping Your App Responsive](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) and related docs chapters.

Comment: Smth like: 
 fun do_calc(n: BigInteger) = runBlocking(CommonPool) {
        val result = async { 
            tail_recursion_factorial(n)
        }
        result.await()
    } 
Would help?

Comment: @AndreiPaciurca like your code states: it's blocking. You have to make sure to run it really asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You message might not be a the actual error, but states the reason clearly.

The so-called UI-Thread is used to render the frames to the display. If you're doing heavy work on it, you'll block this rendering and your app halts.

So instead of doing everything on the UI-Thread, you have to schedule the work on a different thread and communicate the UI updates back to the UI-Thread.

There are different possible pattern to implement such.

- [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)
- [Kotlin coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)
- [`RxJava`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)
- …

Just have a look and try it yourself. You just need to be aware of only updating view properties on the UI-Thread. Otherwise you'll crash with a different reason again.